# Adding stop loss and take profit together in a pine script

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to use Trailing Take profit and trailing stop loss in my strategy. I am using trail_offset and trail_points inside the strategy.exit function. Using this function twice, once for long and then for short. However this adds Trailing take profit functionality to my strategy, how do I add trailing stop losses now?
A sample code is attached to which I am willing to add a trailing stop loss with 5%.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
//Take profit and Stop Loss
strategy.exit("long exit","Long",trail_points=0.1*close/syminfo.mintick,trail_offset=0.05*close/syminfo.mintick)
strategy.exit("short exit","Short",trail_points=0.1*close/syminfo.mintick,trail_offset=0.05*close/syminfo.mintick)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are `loss` parameter for this:

```
strategy.exit("short exit","Short",trail_points=0.1*close/syminfo.mintick,trail_offset=0.05*close/syminfo.mintick, loss = ...)
```

your full script will be:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
//Take profit and Stop Loss
strategy.exit("long exit","Long",trail_points=0.1*close/syminfo.mintick,trail_offset=0.05*close/syminfo.mintick,loss=0.05*close/syminfo.mintick)
strategy.exit("short exit","Short",trail_points=0.1*close/syminfo.mintick,trail_offset=0.05*close/syminfo.mintick,loss=0.05*close/syminfo.mintick)
```

Comment: I thought of this too, But this will be just another regular stop loss right? I'm trying to have different trail offsets for Take profit and stop loss. Ex: For take profit: Trail points=10,offset=3. For stop loss: Trail points=0, offset =5. Can't think of a way to do it in a single script

Comment: the `strategy.exit` can work with both - stop & trailing stop. Until trailing amount will be reached position will be protected by stop. After that only trailing stop will work.

Comment: What if I want to use different values of trailing points for take profit and stop loss?

Comment: This is doable.

Comment: Doable, but how?

Comment: strategy.exit("short exit","Short",trail_points=0.1*close/syminfo.mintick,trail_offset=0.05*close/syminfo.mintick, loss=0.05*close/syminfo.mintick )